# jQuery inputmask datetime not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, mask, jquery-inputmask

I'm trying to apply the datetime mask on an input but this didn't work 
the jQuery plugin I used is [inputmask](http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/)
I did my code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/fayekramzy/pen/GEBGXp) site and include all needed js libraries but don't have any idea why this not work

```
<input id="datetime" />

$('#datetime').inputmask({
    mask: "2/1/y h:s t\\m",
    placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm xm",
    alias: "datetime",
    hourFormat: "12"
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with [Inputmask](http://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/), but *fiddling* around with your **Pen**... this seems to work for me:

```
<input id="datetime" />

$('#datetime').inputmask({                
    placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm xm",
    alias: "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm xm",
    hourFormat: "12"
});
```